Is there any particular value of the constant $C$?
For the ordinary differential equation $xy \log(\frac{x}{y})dx+(y^2-x^2\log(\frac{x}{y}))dy=0$ I am getting the general solution $\frac{x^2}{2y^2}log(\frac{x}{y}-\frac{x^2}{4y^2}+log(y))=C.$ and it is given to us that $y(1)=0$. Is it possible to get any value of $C$. Does any value of $C$ exist? Is the data of the given question valid?

Is the given question wrong ?

Please do not put up duplicates. Update your old question with new insights to push it up in the question stream (of active questions). Per a deleted comment/answer, could you check if the zero in $y(1)=0$ could be a distorted version or wrong transcription of $y(1)=e$ (if the e is large and distorted, it could look like a 0 with a stroke in the middle, somewhat like $\Theta$).

Ah thank you @LutzLehmann for the observation . I think it will work with $y=e$. And thank you for the advice too.

There is an explicit solution for $x(y)$.

@Sillyasker You put the brackets wrong in your general solution.

This is correct: $\frac{x^2}{2y^2}log(\frac{x}{y})-\frac{x^2}{4y^2}+log(y)=C$
